# inlineMath \$...\$ not working but default \(...\) does

Tags: tex-core, inline, mathjax, javascript

I am having issues getting a custom inlineMath format to work.

I have included the MathJax CDN and then using the in-line configuration options. I can get all of the default formats to work `$$...$$`, `\[...\]`, and `\(---\)`

I want to add `\$...\$` to the inlineMath formats but it is not working at all.
Here is the test Tex I am using to test all formats:

```
\$\frac{Math}{Jax}\$
```

This is what is currently in my header:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config;executed=true">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({"HTML-CSS": { preferredFont: "TeX", availableFonts: ["STIX","TeX"], linebreaks: { automatic:true }, EqnChunk: (MathJax.Hub.Browser.isMobile ? 10 : 50) },
        tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ["\\$", "\\$"], ["\\(", "\\)"] ], displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"], ["\\[", "\\]"] ], processEscapes: true, ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore|dno" },
        TeX: {  noUndefined: { attributes: { mathcolor: "red", mathbackground: "#FFEEEE", mathsize: "90%" } } },
        messageStyle: "none"
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"></script>
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  Inline math is _not_ `\$`, but rather just `$`. At leat in TeX, not sure about Mathjax.

Comment: @PeterGrill I wanted to add \$. Just answered my own question though. Thanks for taking a look at my question!

Comment: Also, not sure if MathJax questions are on topic here, so this might get closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I found out the problem a bit after asking but it was a small issue that I think many may overlook.

I copied the code from a demo page and the `executed=true` was already set on the script tag.

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config;executed=true">
```

**Make sure to remove that parameter if you want it to execute when the page loads.** The proper way to do it is:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({"HTML-CSS": { preferredFont: "TeX", availableFonts: ["STIX","TeX"], linebreaks: { automatic:true }, EqnChunk: (MathJax.Hub.Browser.isMobile ? 10 : 50) },
        tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ["\\$", "\\$"], ["\\(", "\\)"] ], displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"], ["\\[", "\\]"] ], processEscapes: true, ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore|dno" },
        TeX: {  noUndefined: { attributes: { mathcolor: "red", mathbackground: "#FFEEEE", mathsize: "90%" } } },
        messageStyle: "none"
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"></script>
```

Comment: I think if you define your own inline math, it might be a good idea to use the ones, that are compatible with LaTeX. `$` is one usual way to start (and end) inline math, not `\$` (which is printing a Dollar symbol), you're already defining (my favourite) `\(` and `\)` from `amsmath` - so you could - for compatibility, just stick to `$` in stead of `\$`.

Comment: @Ronny `\(` and `\)` are not from `amsmath` but from (pure) LaTeX.

Comment: \$ is not escaping $ for me. I need to put it in span to make it visible. I am using the script mentioned above.